# Connection reader

Tags: java, io, connection

I have an occasion where I need to return a reader from a given url. In this case, the url is always has a protocol like http or https. I have no trouble at all creating the code for that.

I am wondering what better practise is, the former method or latter?

```
public Reader getContents (final URL url) {
    try {
        final Reader stream = new InputStreamReader(url.openConnection().getInputStream());
        final StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

        int character;
        while ((character = stream.read()) != -1)
            builder.append((char)character);
        stream.close();
        return new StringReader(builder.toString());
    } catch (final IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

This method first creates a String from the URL content, and then returns a reader of that String. In the following code, I am just returning the InputStreamReader. One of my worries is that the input stream doesn't get closed by the reader because the `Reader.close()` method might not be called. I am wondering what is worse, not closing the connection inputstream or closing the string inputstream.

Here is the second method, which is straight forward:

```
public Reader getContents (final URL url) {
    try {
        return new InputStreamReader(url.openStream());
    } catch (final IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

It makes sense to do former, but does it make any difference at all?

**EDIT**
I have made the method just like the accepted answer:

```
public static Reader getContents (final URL url) {
    try {
        final HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.connect();

        String charset = connection.getHeaderField("Content-Type");
        if (charset == null)
            charset = "UTF-8";
        else
            charset = charset.replaceAll(".*charset=(.*)", "$1");

        return new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream(), charset);
    } catch (final IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you intend to expose the data as a `Reader` (which is more difficult to consume than just a `String`), then the 2nd approach gains the benefits of using a `Reader` - namely limiting amount of memory consumed.

You should also specify the character encoding to use. You should check the http response content type to see if charset has been specified. If that is not present, the http default is iso-8859-1, so that should be used unless the specific service you are calling has specified something different. Your current approach uses the default character encoding of the platform, which likely cannot be guaranteed to be correct.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have made a new method, which can be seen in the former post :)